# WordPress GiveWP Plugin showing blank page in none default theme

Tags: plugins, jquery

I am using the `GiveWP` plugin with a `U-Design theme`.

The donation page shows *preloader* for short time then turn into a **blank page**:

I.E. In this page: https://www.podrsd.org/donations/support-needy-families/

I noticed in Googe Chrome's Browser that there are 11 elements with 'Slow network detected' and jQuery-Migrate-3.3.2 is sometimes loaded sometimes 2 times!

Could this be the problem why the donation page is turned, Blank?

When I deactivate the `U-Desing theme` and Activate the `2022 theme` it works perfectly.

[image]

**Update:**
PHP version is 8.0.1 and Error Reporting is enabled in PHP.INI but I don't see any error.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iframe that has the Give form, there's this line, repeated twice:

```
<style id="alpha-critical-css">body{opacity: 0;}</style>
```

All you need to do is to remove it for it to work. Does that ring any bells? If it's hard to figure out, you could try searching the codebase and see where `alpha-critical-css` is coming from.

By the way, I found this just by deleting sections of the CSS in the browser inspector until it was fixed.

Comment: Thank you Nabha!, Indeed this will solve it; but I searched all plugin's files using Notepad++ but got 0 hits! Any idea please?

Comment: @Guru, do you have a way to search all of wp-content? It sounds like the most likely culprit is the theme, but it doesn't hurt to look beyond it.

Comment: Yes @nabha! I found it in the theme core! Is it safe to delete it? I used string locator plugin.

Comment: Since you didn't write the theme, it might be something to check with the theme developer about and see if you can get it patched. Otherwise a later update to the theme might revert the site back to having this problem again.

Honestly, if the fix is urgently needed, it's probably OK to delete. But I'd still suggest connecting with the developer.

Comment: Thank you @nabha, you saved my day! Appreciated your time and efforts!

Comment: Dear @nabha, how did you figure out that this could be the problem? What are your steps? It could be many other thigs? Why `alpha-critical-css`?

Comment: Good question! I used the browser inspector and just poked around, looking at different elements, and then the <head> inside the <iframe> — deleting large chunks of CSS, then undoing — until I narrowed down the cause.

Comment: WOW @Nabha, you spent so much efforrt and time! Apprecaited! Thank you!